# Error then entering ApplicicationId and Application Key on dnn.azureadb2cprovider settings page

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

If I enter both an ApplicationID and key into the Advanced Settings of the dnn.azureadb2cprovider  I get a generic error with no explanation.  I've gone through the setup documentation (which seems to be outdated) numerous times.  The error gives no clue as to what the issue is.

If I enter only the app id or only key by itself, there is no error.  Obviously this wont allow Graph to work, but I am noting it anyway.

[image]

Went thought the setup process located at https://github.com/intelequia/dnn.azureadb2cprovider#requirements.   I can get users to sign in successfully through B2C so it's partially working.  Just the advanced features are having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the log4net log files under /Portals/_default/Logs folder for more details on the issue. This is probably caused by the permissions of the App registration on the Graph API. Ensure that you have set permissions on these Application scopes and have given consent to them (the documentation will be updated soon):

- Application.Read.All
- Group.Read.All
- GroupMember.Read.All
- User.Read.All

PS: in the future please create this type of issues on the GitHub repository to concentrate all the help and documentation on the same location.